# Connecting two sensors to one analog pin

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, analog

I am completely new to programming with Arduino so please bear with me if this seems stupid.

I am using an Arduino Uno R3. 
I have two sensors, a Soil Moisture sensor and an LDR Light Sensor. Both of them have one pin marked as A0 on them. So now, do I connect them both to A0 using a breadboard (Like how I am connecting multiple sensors' VCC to the 5V pin currently) OR do I use a different analog pin say A0 for one and A1 for the other? Will it make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AO is not "Ay Zero", it's "Ay Oh", and stands for "Analog Output". It means it just sends a varying voltage. It really doesn't care where it's sent to, it just sends it.

It's up to you where you connect that *output* to. But suffice it to say it wants to be connected to an *input* that can read an *analog signal*. And the Arduino has 6 of them.

Which one you connect it to is entirely up to you - you just have to *read* from that analog input by using the right pin number in `analogRead()`.

Answer (score 0):

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm3On.jpg)
you can simply connect one in the A0 and the other in the A1 since all those pins can be used for the same function